# Двумерные и вложенные списки в Python

Tags: python, list

В литературных источниках довелось встретить утверждение, что вложенные списки и двумерные одно и то же. Понятие двумерного списка: двумерный список —  это список,  который  в качестве своих элементов  содержит другие списки. Например, есть у меня список my_list = [[1],[2],[3]]. Список my_list - будет двумерным, так как содержит в себе списки, но... этот список вложенным никак нельзя назвать, поскольку он не является составной частью другого списка....т.е. понятия уже не тождественны. И вот вложенные списки у меня [1],[2],[3].Эти вложенные списки я разве могу назвать двумерными? Нет, так как эти вложенные списки не включают другие списки. Помогите, пожалуйста. Я, например, эти понятия не могу назвать идентичными. Видимо, что-то недопонимаю.

Comment: На списке вида `my_list = [[1], "wtf", [None]]` все эти рассуждения рассыпаются в прах, так что по-моему такие манипуляции с терминологией изначально не имеют смысла

Comment: я пока новичок. пытаюсь логикой познавать пайтон))))

Comment: А если сделать `my_list = []; my_list.append(my_list)` то, согласно таким рассуждениям, можно получить бесконечномерный список 

Comment: Вы понимаете под вложенным списком список, который сам куда-то вложен. А в терминологии питона вложенный список это список, который содержит в себе другие списки. Вот и все. Возможно, трудности перевода английского nested list.

Comment: Эникейщик, да всё верно вы описали. Спасибо большое Вам за помощь. Да, я тоже такое в книжке прочитала, не в одной....и удивилась, ни на шутку))))Подумала, что явно неправильно поняла....СПАСИБО ОТ ДУШИ.

Comment: andreymal да, интересная запись. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не знаю, станет ли понятнее...

```
# одномерный список
lst = [1, 2, 3]
print(lst[1])  # чтобы адресовать любой элемент списка, достаточно одного "измерения" (индекса в квадратных скобках) - поэтому он одномерный

# двухмерный список
# двухмерный список - это частный случай вложенного списка, а количество измерений неограничено
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
print(lst[1][1])  # чтобы адресовать любой элемент списка, нужно два "измерения" (индекса в квадратных скобках) - поэтому он двухмерный

# трехмерный список
lst = [[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], [[10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18]], [[19, 20, 21], [22, 23, 24], [25, 26, 27]]]
print(lst[1][1][1])  # чтобы адресовать любой элемент списка, нужно три "измерения" (индекса в квадратных скобках) - поэтому он трехмерный

# и так далее
# при этом списки могут содержать любые элементы, в т.ч. другие списки, строки, числа, функции, словари ... даже сами себя
```

```
2
5
14
```

Comment: ВСЁ ПОНЯТНО. ОТВЕТ ОЧЕНЬ ПРЕКРАСНЫЙ У ВАС.

Comment: Кстати...например, берем трехмерный список из вашего примера.....как понимаю, [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]] - это двухмерный список, находящийся в трехмерном списке....т.е запись  print(lst[0]) либо print(lst[1]), либо print(lst[2]) позволит нам обратиться к элементу (ДВУХМЕРНОМУ списку, находящемуся в трехмерном списке). Немного пытаюсь поразмышлять...